# Storm Trident Topology with Kafka: Received unexpected tuple error

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm, trident

We have a Trident topology that both consumes from and produces to kafka using the kafka-storm OpaqueTridentKafkaSpout and TridentKafkaState.  Everything works fine when running on our production storm cluster, but when run in local mode we very often receive the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Received unexpected tuple source: $mastercoord-bg1:2, stream: $commit, id: {-4957901903366351898=6364388931843393707}, [1:0]
    at backtype.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchToCursor(DisruptorQueue.java:128) ~[storm-core-0.10.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.10.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at backtype.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchWhenAvailable(DisruptorQueue.java:99) ~[storm-core-0.10.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.10.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at backtype.storm.disruptor$consume_batch_when_available.invoke(disruptor.clj:80) ~[storm-core-0.10.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.10.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__4606$fn__4619$fn__4670.invoke(executor.clj:806) ~[storm-core-0.10.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.10.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__543.invoke(util.clj:475) ~[storm-core-0.10.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.10.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22) [clojure-1.6.0.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_31]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Received unexpected tuple source: $mastercoord-bg1:2, stream: $commit, id: {-4957901903366351898=6364388931843393707}, [1:0]
    at storm.trident.planner.SubtopologyBolt.execute(SubtopologyBolt.java:144) ~[storm-core-0.10.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.10.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at storm.trident.topology.TridentBoltExecutor.execute(TridentBoltExecutor.java:369) ~[storm-core-0.10.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.10.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__4606$tuple_action_fn__4608.invoke(executor.clj:668) ~[storm-core-0.10.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.10.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$mk_task_receiver$fn__4529.invoke(executor.clj:424) ~[storm-core-0.10.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.10.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at backtype.storm.disruptor$clojure_handler$reify__1229.onEvent(disruptor.clj:58) ~[storm-core-0.10.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.10.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at backtype.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchToCursor(DisruptorQueue.java:125) ~[storm-core-0.10.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.10.0-SNAPSHOT]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
```

We also see this error as part of the same error dump:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.storm.zookeeper.KeeperException$NodeExistsException: KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /errors/<topology-name>/<bolt-name>-last-error
    at backtype.storm.util$wrap_in_runtime.invoke(util.clj:48) ~[storm-core-0.10.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.10.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at backtype.storm.zookeeper$create_node.invoke(zookeeper.clj:92) ~[storm-core-0.10.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.10.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at backtype.storm.cluster$mk_distributed_cluster_state$reify__2234.set_data(cluster.clj:104) ~[storm-core-0.10.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.10.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at backtype.storm.cluster$mk_storm_cluster_state$reify__2774.report_error(cluster.clj:450) ~[storm-core-0.10.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.10.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$throttled_report_error_fn$fn__4385.invoke(executor.clj:191) ~[storm-core-0.10.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.10.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$mk_executor_data$fn__4439$fn__4440.invoke(executor.clj:253) ~[storm-core-0.10.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.10.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__543.invoke(util.clj:485) ~[storm-core-0.10.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.10.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22) ~[clojure-1.6.0.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
Caused by: org.apache.storm.zookeeper.KeeperException$NodeExistsException: KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /errors/<topology-name>/<bolt-name>-last-error
    at org.apache.storm.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:119) ~[storm-core-0.10.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.10.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.storm.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51) ~[storm-core-0.10.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.10.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.storm.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.create(ZooKeeper.java:783) ~[storm-core-0.10.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.10.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.storm.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl$11.call(CreateBuilderImpl.java:676) ~[storm-core-0.10.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.10.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.storm.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl$11.call(CreateBuilderImpl.java:660) ~[storm-core-0.10.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.10.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.storm.curator.RetryLoop.callWithRetry(RetryLoop.java:107) ~[storm-core-0.10.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.10.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.storm.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl.pathInForeground(CreateBuilderImpl.java:656) ~[storm-core-0.10.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.10.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.storm.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl.protectedPathInForeground(CreateBuilderImpl.java:441) ~[storm-core-0.10.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.10.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.storm.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl.forPath(CreateBuilderImpl.java:431) ~[storm-core-0.10.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.10.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.storm.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl$3.forPath(CreateBuilderImpl.java:239) ~[storm-core-0.10.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.10.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.storm.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl$3.forPath(CreateBuilderImpl.java:193) ~[storm-core-0.10.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.10.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor24.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod(Reflector.java:93) ~[clojure-1.6.0.jar:na]
    at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeInstanceMethod(Reflector.java:28) ~[clojure-1.6.0.jar:na]
    at backtype.storm.zookeeper$create_node.invoke(zookeeper.clj:91) ~[storm-core-0.10.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.10.0-SNAPSHOT]
    ... 7 common frames omitted
```

Currently using the latest storm 0.10.0-SNAPSHOT built from [github](https://github.com/apache/storm), but the same issue was occuring with the stable 0.9.3 release.  Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: At a brief glance, looks like this got filed as https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/STORM-709?

Answer (score 0):

In LocalCluster mode, if you're deploying multiple topologies then name the Spouts uniquely *across topologies*.

`TestTopology`: Spout1 -> Bolt1 -> Bolt2...

`DummyTopology`: Spout1 -> Bolt1 -> Bolt2...

The aforementioned leads to `KeeperException` as Storm gets confused to which Spout to refer to in case of re-emit attempt, batch failure etc.

The correct way:

`TestTopology`: **TestTopology-Spout1** -> Bolt1 -> Bolt2...

`DummyTopology`: **DummyTopology-Spout1** -> Bolt1 -> Bolt2...

Answer (score -1):

I just met the `KeeperException$NodeExistsException` because I inited 2 spouts and gave them the same ID. Change one of the IDs and the problem will be resolved.